# HTML Table, Right Justify Cell (Not Contents)

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have a website I am working on, which can be view at this link: http://consumer.hdscores.com/consumer/share?item=be0c0264db25f3ead4a1af

I would like the `%` score on the right to be justified in the table on the right.   This works fine in Firefox, but does not in Safari but don't know (after trying many times) how to get it to work.   The `%` is in the following code:

```
<tr style="padding: 0px;">
     <td style="width: 100%; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
     <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; border: 5px solid #FFFFFF; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; background-color:#8F2000; visibility: visible;">
</tr>
```

Any thoughts?   As I said, it looks good in Firefox, but not Safari on my mac, and not Safari on IOS (which even looks stranger with the border around it that I haven't looked at).

Any help in right aligning the cell in the table?

Comment: you could simply add `width: 100%;` to the style of the table (just tested on chrome, works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width:100% of that table I tried it and worked